# Trying to export private spreadsheet using SheetsService.HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to export a Google Spreadsheet as a .xlsx file. To do so, I've started using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 library. There I'm creating `SheetsService` and using `Google.Apis.Services.IClientService.HttpClient` to do the request to the Google API.
*https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={0}&gid={1}&exportFormat=xlsx*

It works correctly with public documents, but I'm facing an issue with private spreadsheets.
For authentication, my application uses a service account with the public key, and from the spreadsheets UI, I gave access to that document for that account.
The fun thing is I **can** request information from that spreadsheet via `Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.Get` method.

My question is: Why I can't access a document via HttpClient and can do that via `SheetsService`?

The code sample I use to do the call:

```
using (var service = GoogleSheetsHelper.GetService(settings))
{
  var exportUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={0}&gid={1}&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var requestResult = await service.HttpClient.GetAsync(exportUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
  if (!requestResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }

  return await requestResult.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

What is also interesting - `requestResult.IsSuccessStatusCode` is always true! Sometimes it just returns html with the google authentication page instead of .xlsx file.

Comment: Have you checked if your scopes are setup properly?
You can download the public ones because they do not require authentication and you can get information about the private sheet because your scopes are set up that way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Currently, I have only one scope `SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly`. During debug, I've also tried `SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets`, but no luck here.
I'll try Drive scopes, maybe they are responsible for the file export.

Comment: @Jescanellas, no, I've just tried to set scopes to `SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, SheetsService.Scope.Drive` and it didn't work with two widest scopes. Probably that is not the cause of an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the Sheets Service for this, instead you should use the Drive Service with the scope `DriveService.Scope.Drive` and to download and export the sheet you have to use the Drive API with it's [export method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using `Sheets service`, to get data and manually convert it to the _JSON_ string and using `Drive service` [export method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) to download the file in _.xlsx_ format.